# (Return view) is returning a limited number of variables

Tags: php, laravel

I'm simply trying to return three variables as shown below. I'm receiving an undefined variable: udraft which is the third variable. If I make them only two variables, it will work. Is there some limitation here?

```
return view('tabs', ['post' => $posts]  , ['acc' => $acc_usrs] , ['udraft' => $usr_draft]);
```

Comment: Use `return view('tabs', ['post' => $posts, 'acc' => $acc_usrs, 'udraft' => $usr_draft]);`. Or use `->with()`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not returning one array like this:

```
return view('tabs', [
    'post'   => $posts,
    'acc'    => $acc_usrs,
    'udraft' => $usr_draft
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the Laravel Documentation, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views), you should pass an array of data, not a single array for each variable.
Your code should be something like: 
`return view('tabs', ['post' => $posts, 'acc' => $acc_usrs, 'udraft' => $usr_draft]);`

Or use the `->with()` method as mentioned in the documentation above.

Answer (score 1):

you can use compact

```
return view('tabs', compact('posts','acc_usrs','usr_draft'));
```